# PHP strpos is not working

Tags: php, arrays

List array:

```
[lists] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 1
                    [Name] => Bunglows
                    [Property_type] => 
                    [Status] => Open
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 2
                    [Name] => Tenament
                    [Property_type] => 
                    [Status] => Open
                )

        )
```

Amenity Types array:

```
[amenitytypes] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 13
                    [Name] => College
                    [Amenity_property_ID] => 14
                    [Property_name] => Bunglows,Tenament
                )

        )
```

PHP function

```
                  <?php foreach($lists as $list):?>
                    <?php if(strpos(trim($amenitytype['Property_name']), trim($list['Name'])) == TRUE):?>
                      <label class="checkbox-inline">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" class="Propertytype" value="<?php echo $list['ID']?>" checked> <?php echo trim($list['Name']);?>
                      </label>
                    <?php else:?>
                      <label class="checkbox-inline">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" class="Propertytype" value="<?php echo $list['ID']?>"> <?php echo trim($list['Name']);?>
                      </label>
                    <?php endif;?>
                  <?php endforeach;?>
```

strpos function is not working for me. during code execution Tenament is checked but Bunglows are not checked. how to I resolve this issue. Bunglows value are same in lists and amenitytypes. I don't know why my function is not working. can you please help me how to resolve this error?

Comment: use `!== false`instead

Comment: I know it's probably preference.. But why not just use `{ ... }` (curly braces) as opposed to `: ... endif;`? Seems a bit unnecessary...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the line you are using multidimensional array if you use $amenitytype['Property_name']. there is no property in the name Property_name in $amenitytype array

```
if(strpos(trim($amenitytype['Property_name']), trim($list['Name'])) == TRUE):?>
```

To

```
if(strpos(trim($amenitytype[0]['Property_name']), trim($list['Name'])) !== false):?>
```

Comment: Brother lists is a nested foreach. so I can't write $amenitytype[0]['Property_name'] like this

Answer (score 0):

You should use `!== FALSE` instead of `== TRUE` as strpos may return 0 which will be considered as not true, while in fact it points to the first character in the haystack.

Also your code isn't clear what `$amenitytype` contains so you may have to replace this line

`<?php if(strpos(trim($amenitytype['Property_name']), trim($list['Name'])) == TRUE):?>`

with this

`<?php if(strpos(trim($amenitytypes[0]['Property_name']), trim($list['Name'])) !== FALSE):?>`